# Good algorithm for managing configuration trees with wildcards?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, configuration, tree

I am searching for a good algorithm for managing configuration variables in form of tree with wildcards (x.y.z, x.*.z, x.*.* etc.).

Is there something with search time better than O(N)? (insert / delete time are not so important).

Currently I have a flat list (pairs key=>value), and I search all matching values, then sort them by importance (basically, more wildcards => less important) and choose one with best score.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you're trying to do?  What queries do you want to support?

Comment: ie. having list of keys x.*.*, x.*.z, x.y.* and search string x.y.z i have to return value for key x.*.z. Searching for x.y.v returns x.y.*, searching for v.y.z returns nothing.

Comment: Is there a special significance to the dot?  I presume * does not match .?

Comment: yes, dot is a separator and * does not match it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As epitaph points out, a trie or radix-tree will do the trick. A radix-tree will generally be more space efficent.

I guess there are a dozens of implementations out there. Take a look at my implementation [here](https://github.com/foolano/py-trie/blob/master/trie.py).

*lookup()* will allow you to search for a given key.

*startwith()* will return all those keys and their corresponding values that start with the passed string. It is effectively a wild-card search.

Comment: Note that once you have reached a leaf in a radix-tree you still have to compare the remaining part of the string. That makes both trees O(K). But I guess in the real world a radix-tree will be slightly faster.

Comment: yes, sure, but I've a kart-trie and in kart-trie you don't need to compare the remaining part of the string so it is O(log(n)) or O(log(k)*log(n)).

Comment: I don't know about real world, didn't tried it, and it seems that the author and inventor didn't know it either: http://code.dogmap.org/kart/. But the time complexity of a binary tree is O(log(n)), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a trie-datastructure or a radix-tree. When you want to search for a wildcard just use the inverse trie with the trie together. You can find a simple solution here: code.dogmap.org/kart.